# Remove a part of url from the middle in nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am writing to ask for your help on how to redirect a URL in nginx.
I would like to remove part of the central URL.

The URL in question is as follows:

**Original**:
https://example.com/campaigns/jf798l9w3a872/track-url/nm3736ss3md99/d24172761e223c60ae3675f8e7f2a61b1c94ac7d

**I wish it would become like this**:
https://example.com/campaigns/jf798l9w3a872/nm3736ss3md99/d24172761e223c60ae3675f8e7f2a61b1c94ac7d

I would therefore like to remove only "track-url" in the middle part of the URL.
The parts of the URL between "campaigns" and "track-url" and after are all dynamic and not static.

I have been trying the method suggested by NGINX for days but without success:

> rewrite ^/campaigns/(\w+)/track-url/(\w+)$ $1/$2 last;

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Besides the other errors, a slash in the `nm3736ss3md99/d24172761e223c60ae3675f8e7f2a61b1c94ac7d` part of your URL prevents the `(\w+)$` regex pattern part from being matched (`\w` metacharacter does not include a slash). You can change it to be anything with the `^/campaigns/(\w+)/track-url/(.*$)` regex pattern. And you probably want the `rewrite ^/campaigns/(\w+)/track-url/(.*$) /campaings/$1/$2 last;` rule instead.

Comment: It works! Thanks Ivan ..
I replaced for myself only last with permanent and everything worked.
I would like to reward you but I don't know how!